# Control files provided by MTP in Android device

Tags: android, mtp

I wonder if it is possible to write an app to control the file access when the device is connected via USB (in Devices which support MTP).

I think it would be very useful when you are about to connect your phone to a foreign computer and could determine the folders / files the computer can see and has access to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the MTP contents are served by a low-level system process, this will not be possible, except perhaps on rooted phones or via a custom ROM mod.

Comment: Well I have a rooted phone. I just have no Idea where to start inspecting the system service...